# How can I make PowerShell run the original Start-Process cmdlet rather than the PSCX Start-Process cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, pscx

I have PowerShell v2.0 installed and on top of that, PSCX is installed. PSCX is the PowerShell Community Extensions (http://pscx.codeplex.com/Wikipage).

It seems that I have two cmdlets called Start-Process installed and I'm guessing one is the original and the other is from PSCX. When I invoke Start-Process, the PSCX cmdlet is made to run. **How can I make PowerShell run the original version instead?**

Helpful Evidence:

When I run `get-help start-process` i get:

```
Name                              Category  Synopsis
----                              --------  --------
Start-Process                     Cmdlet    PSCX Cmdlet: Starts a new process.
Start-Process                     Cmdlet    Starts one or more processes on the local computer.
```

When I run `get-command start-process` I get:

```
CommandType     Name                                                          Definition
-----------     ----                                                          ----------
Cmdlet          Start-Process                                                 Start-Process [[-Path] <String>] [[-Arguments] <String>] [...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you grab the module-based version (PSCX 2.0 Beta), you can choose not to import the Pscx.Deprecated module which contains the three PSCX cmdlets that clash with the built-in PowerShell cmdlets: Start-Process, Select-Xml and Get-Random.  Note the PSCX 2.0 Beta is an xcopy deploy requiring you to only do this:

1. Download the Pscx-2.0-Beta2.zip
2. Open its properties in Windows Explorer
   and press the Unblock located on the
   General tab.  This is required
   otherwise you'll get a lot of errors
   when you import the module.
3. Extract the files (preserving the folder
   structure) into
   ~\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
4. Import-Module Pscx

That's it.  If you need to re-enable the "Open PowerShell Here" context menu entry in Windows Explorer then run the command `Enable-OpenPowerShellHere`.

Answer (score 3):

I have these aliases set up:

```
new-alias start-pscxprocess pscx\start-process 
new-alias start-msprocess microsoft.powershell.management\start-process
```